# Dropdown loaded async doesn't work (Zurb Foundation)

Tags: zurb-foundation

Using zurb foundation 5, I have multiple alert boxes that render dropdowns synchronously and asynchronously.

The syncronous dropdowns work as intended.

**The async dropdowns have no popup when clicked on.**

Is there a javascript call I should be doing to zurb foundation once the async call is returned to have the dropdown magic applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

The javascript load() function has an option for a callback where I simply called "foundation()" on the scope of the loaded item.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".partial").each(function(index, item) {
            var url = $(item).data("url");
            if (url && url.length > 0) {
                $(item).load(url, { ... }, function() {
                    $(item).foundation();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Minor optimization would\(could) be calling `$('.partial').foundation()` after the loop instead of inside the `each`. Or you could even chain it after the each, jQuery-style =)